# One solution on how to configure CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to configure CodeIgniter, so I am following this guide:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/how-to-install-and-use-codeigniter-on-your-server/

I don't understand where I unzip the CodeIgniter folder to. I have installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL with XAPP. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you give us any details?  Are you trying to install this locally or on an actual server?  Do you already have a running website you're trying to install it in place of?

Comment: This question should of been asked on http://forum.codeigniter.com and main website http://www.codeigniter.com. Also there are quite a few tutorials on you tube on how to install and setup codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed XAMPP in local on C:, you have to unzip it there:

C:/xampp/htdocs/ci

And then in you can use it that way in your browser this way:

localhost/ci

or

127.0.0.1/ci

Comment: It's my pleasure, have a nice day :-)